# Sortable table columns in django

Tags: django

I want to have sortable columns in my tables (just like what is done for the admin changelists)....I'm looking for a solution that will be easy to implement and customize if I want.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Javascript? There are plenty of table sorters out there:

- http://tablesorter.com/docs/
- http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/
- http://friedcellcollective.net/js/SortedTable/
- http://www.leigeber.com/2009/03/table-sorter/
- http://www.millstream.com.au/view/code/tablekit

Comment: tablesorter is a great and supported toolkit.  The link above is old - make sure to look on https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I prefer [datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html).

Answer (score 57):

If you use pagination rather than a Javascript table sorter, it might not be sufficient or behave unexpected.

---

Create every column header as a link e.g.

```
<th><a href="?order_by=name">Name</a></th>
```

and in your view you check whether the `order_by` parameter is set or not:

```
order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', 'defaultOrderField')
Model.objects.all().order_by(order_by)
```

Comment: I think the ";" at the end of the `order_by` code line is unnecessary. I can't edit it because the edit needs to be at least 6 chars.

Comment: @la_f0ka: Thanks... I was always switching back and forth between JavaScript and Python ;)

Comment: np, thank you,... I didn't know how to do this and I was about to install yet another app to handle it, when it's actually so simple.

Comment: This is pretty elegant, but how to solve ascending/descending problem?

Comment: @SummerBreeze use ?order_by=name&sort={{ ascend_or_descend}} and check for existence in your view

Comment: @SummerBreeze use ?order_by=name&sort={{ sort_type }} and check for existence in your view

        order_by = "-%s" % order_by if sort_type == "descending" else order_by
        context['sort_type'] = "descending" if sort_type == "ascending" else "ascending"

Comment: If you don't want any specific ordering by default, you can just write 'id' in the place of 'defaultOrderField' and they will retain the original order

Answer (score 11):

I used the approach followed by the most voted answer above. But I solve the ascending/descending ordering when clicking multiple times on the column header by using a custom tag.

The tag:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from collections import OrderedDict

@register.simple_tag
def url_replace(request, field, value, direction=''):
    dict_ = request.GET.copy()

    if field == 'order_by' and field in dict_.keys():          
      if dict_[field].startswith('-') and dict_[field].lstrip('-') == value:
        dict_[field] = value
      elif dict_[field].lstrip('-') == value:
        dict_[field] = "-" + value
      else:
        dict_[field] = direction + value
    else:
      dict_[field] = direction + value

    return urlencode(OrderedDict(sorted(dict_.items())))
```

Then you use this tag on your column header, like above:

```
<th><a href="?{% url_replace request 'order_by' 'name' '-' %}">Name</a></th>
```

First time you click it will sort in 'descending' order, if you click the same header again it will revert to 'ascending' order.

This approach also preserves other parameters in your URL, like page number if you are using a paginator. It requires no extra libraries. Only thing you need to make sure is that your view is sending the RequestContext to the template.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you have a look at [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/). It's designed to solve your exact problem. The [documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/) has a bunch of examples.

Comment: It looks like Bradley moved his [fork](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2) and the [docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: Thanks David, I edited most of the posts I could find to refer to the new name, but I guess I missed this one :(

Answer (score 1):

continuing on the most voted answer above by Felix Kling and the addition by mpaf and ngeek, when using class based views: 
do the sorting in the get_queryset(self) method, and use:

```
<th><a href="?{% url_replace view.request 'order_by' 'name' '-' %}">Name</a></th>
```

instead of just request in your template