# how to sort the rows according to the particular column value in python Django

Tags: python, django

we have a table and we want to print the table according to the status. Status is one of the column name. That status should be ok, unreachable, alert and we want the row whose status is ok that will show on top. so my question is where i have to write the code i.e inside the model.py or view.py .

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When



class result(models.Model):
   status = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    ......
    .....


    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()  # super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    return qs.annotate(
        priority=Case(
            When(status='Ok', then=Value(1)),
            When(status='Alert', then=Value(2)),
            When(status='Unreachable', then=Value(3)),
            When(status='Expired', then=Value(4)),
            When(status='Warning', then=Value(5)),
            default=Value(5),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    ).order_by('priority')
```

**view.py**

```
class resultListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, ObjectListView):
   permission_required = 'nameplugi.view_result_status'
   queryset = result.objects.all()
   filterset = Filter
   filterset_form = resultFilterForm
   table=resultTable
   def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()  # super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    print(queryset)
    return qs.annotate(
        priority=Case(
            When(status='Ok', then=Value(1)),
            When(status='Alert', then=Value(2)),
            When(status='Unreachable', then=Value(3)),
            When(status='Expired', then=Value(4)),
            When(status='Warning', then=Value(5)),
            default=Value(5),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    ).order_by('-priority')
template_name = "nameplugins/plugin.html"
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272370/sortable-table-columns-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate values using [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) to add priorities and then order by it. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()  # super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
    return qs.annotate(
            priority=Case(
                When(status='Ok', then=Value(1)),
                When(status='Alert', then=Value(2)),
                When(status='Unreachable', then=Value(3)),
                default=Value(3),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        ).order_by('priority')
```

### Updated code

```
class resultListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, ObjectListView):
   permission_required = 'nameplugi.view_result_status'
   filterset = Filter
   filterset_form = resultFilterForm
   table=resultTable
   queryset = result.objects.annotate(
                priority=Case(
                    When(status='Ok', then=Value(1)),
                    When(status='Alert', then=Value(2)),
                    When(status='Unreachable', then=Value(3)),
                    default=Value(3),
                    output_field=IntegerField()
                )
            ).order_by('-priority')
    template = "nameplugins/plugin.html"
    orderering = ['-priority']
```

Comment: i have updated the code ..could you please check this

Comment: Can you try .order_by(“-priority”) ?

Comment: BTW, putting this code in model won’t work. Either put it in model manager or in the Class Based View.

Comment: i tried with Class based view ..its not working

Comment: Can you try to debug by printing the queryset values?

Comment: Can you please add that Class based view code in the question?

Comment: What is `ObjectListView`? is it subclassed from  Django's `ListView`?